# Django model fields don't show up in Admin page

Tags: django, model, field

I am a beginner to Django and am having trouble seeing all the Model Fields when I try to load them on the Django Admin page. I add the app correctly in the settings page, do a relative import to the admin page and successfully get the model to show up in the Admin page, but the problem is that most of the time, Fields that I have entered are missing. I usually just displays the last one or two and only if they are TextFields.

[This is all the Fields I enter into the text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOMe9.png)

[But this is all I end up seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fW82.png)

Comment: define your ModelAdmin class, and register it properly

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "," behind most of the lines, e.g.

```
tiltle = models.Texfield()
```

Answer (score 0):

in forms.py use this

```
from yourApp.models import Product 
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

and in models.py daon't use >>,<<

for exmpl :

```
class Product(models.Model):

    fields1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fields2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tiltle = models.Texfield()
```